# How to disable warnings on some generating fakes?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've added some fakes to my project and now I've got this warning in my build output

> Some fakes could not be generated. For complete details, set Diagnostic attribute of the Fakes element in this file to 'true' and rebuild the project.

It's OK that I can't build some fakes for mscorlib.dll.  I understand why. So the warning is pointless and I'd like to suppress it in the error list. But the problem is that this warning doesn't come with a code and so cannot be suppressed in the normal manner.

How can I get rid of these annoying pointless warnings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you generate Fakes with Visual Studio sometimes it produces a `Warning` in the Error Window: `"Warning 1 Some fakes could not be generated. For complete details, set Diagnostic attribute of the Fakes element in this file to 'true' and rebuild the project..."`. It's quite annoying and I too would like to know if there is a way to suppress it! This SO question seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228290/suppressing-microsoft-fakes-warnings

Comment: This is completely clear and answerable (if there is one). I think the poor choice of tag prevented this from getting infront of the right crowd. I'd like an answer, too. This question is right up there in the search results--that's why I'm here. If you see me in the reopen queue, please help out!