# C# Suppress MS Fakes warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, warnings, microsoft-fakes

How can I suppress the warnings generated by MS Fakes in a build ? I already edited the XML file to generate only the elements we need, but it’s not enough.

Error message

> Cannot generate shim for RestServiceHelper`2+<>c: type is not supported because of internal limitations.

XML sample

```
<Fakes xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/"; Diagnostic="false"> 
  <Assembly Name="Common.Api"/> 
  <StubGeneration> 
    <Clear /> 
  </StubGeneration> 
  <ShimGeneration> 
    <Clear /> 
    <Add FullName="RestServiceHelper" /> 
  </ShimGeneration> 
</Fakes>
```

I have already read this thread before asking my question:
[Suppressing Microsoft Fakes warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228290/suppressing-microsoft-fakes-warnings)

Thanks

Comment: What warnings are you getting and what's in the XML file?

Comment: First warning:
"Some fakes could not be generated. For complete details, set Diagnostic attribute of the Fakes element in this file to 'true' and rebuild the project."

With debug:
"Cannot generate shim for RestServiceHelper`2+<>c: type is not supported because of internal limitations."

The XML:

<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="false">
  <Assembly Name="Common.Api"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear />
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear />
    <Add FullName="RestServiceHelper" />
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>

Comment: Without having the .dll in question, it looks like there's a generic type or inner type that's causing an issue.  You might to state the Add more specifically with a '!' (or put a Remove that's more specific) in the XML file according to the naming rules at this Microsoft page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx).  FYI, there's some additional configuration parameters here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajayarora/archive/2014/03/28/configuring-fakes.aspx) which may not apply here.

Comment: @doobop here is the code:
public static async Task Test(string param)

Apparently, Microsoft Fakes doesn't like async methods, but we must create a shim for this method.

The shim:
ShimRestServiceHelper.TestString = (stringRandom) =>
{ ... };

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the warning via the following statement:

```
<Remove TypeName="&lt;&gt;c" />
```

Comment: Wow this worked for me... I had internal class in my assembly and without this I was getting build warning. I copied this in xxx.fakes XML file  under <ShimGeneration> and it worked...

Comment: While this works, it is a hacky workaround. I posted an answer that solves this issue in a much more streamlined fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to avoid this issue is to use a stricter filter in the XML file. Add a `!` character to the end of the filter to use case sensitive precise matching:

```
  <ShimGeneration> 
    <Clear /> 
    <Add FullName="RestServiceHelper!" /> 
  </ShimGeneration>
```

As per the documentation:

[image]